# can't delete one specific record from table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, delete-row

I'm currently frustrated by searching and no article could help me. I want to delete only one row or record but I end up deleting entire record on the table

```
<?php
   // include database connection file
   $databaseHost = 'localhost';
   $databaseName = 'ceksaldo';
   $databaseUsername = 'root';
   $databasePassword = '';

   $conn = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName); 

   // Get id from URL to delete that saldo
   $id = $_GET['id'];

   // Delete saldo row from table based on given id
   //$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM saldo WHERE id=$id");
   $result ="DELETE FROM saldo WHERE id";
   if (mysqli_query($conn, $result)) {
       echo "Record deleted successfully";
   } else {
       echo "Error deleting record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
   }

   mysqli_close($conn);

   // After delete redirect to Home, so that latest saldo list will be displayed.
   echo "<a href=index.php>Home</a>"
?>
```

[A screenshot of a couple of rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJIZ9.png)

I want it to be automatically deleting the specific data. I found in some article they were using id number to delete the record.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't see an "id" column in the screenshot you gave.

Comment: You didn't include the ID value in query: `$result ="DELETE FROM saldo WHERE id = $id";` BTW, use prepared statements to minimize risk of SQL attacks to your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result ="DELETE FROM saldo WHERE id";
```

doesn't say what the id should be. This will delete *every* row!

You should update the query to this, specifying which record to delete.

```
$result ="DELETE FROM saldo WHERE id = $id";
```

The bigger problem is that in the picture of your code you do not have an '`id`' column, so you need to tie your query to something that uniquely identifies every row. You may need to update your table, or you may not be showing us the whole table.

**WARNING**

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: i already do that, but it shows Error deleting record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: What is $id set to? If it's empty or null, you would see the error you mention

Answer (score 1):

If you need to delete a specific row you need to use the ID in `WHERE`

```
DELETE FROM saldo WHERE id=?
```

Because you need to pass a variable to the query, `mysqli_query()` is unsuitable. You must use prepared statement. You can then bind the value and execute.

To send the value to PHP you can use either a link or a form.

Link:

```
<a href="delete.php?id=123">Delete item with ID 123</a>
```

or with form:

```
<form method="get">
<input type="text" name="id" />
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Your fixed code should look something like this. Notice that I have enabled error reporting, which you should always have. I have also added `if` statement, because you only want to execute the query if a specific ID has been passed to your script.

```
<?php

// include database connection file
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'ceksaldo');
$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4'); // always set the charset

// Get id from URL to delete that saldo
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    // Delete saldo row from table based on given id
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM saldo WHERE id=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
}

echo 'No ID selected. No record deleted!';

// After delete redirect to Home, so that latest saldo list will be displayed.
echo "<a href=index.php>Home</a>";
```